# CSHTML Razor @Html.NavItem In-Line CSS Style

Tags: razor

I'm trying to avoid a writing a CSS Class and specify a style for a `@HTML.NavItem` In-Line and looking for a way to do it.

```
@Html.NavItem("Card", "Cards", "Card", new { @class = "left-menu-item"})
```

I want to add `display:none` to this Nav Item. Couldn't find any help for this on online.

Comment: To apply a style it would either be inline or via CSS.  Why don't you want to use either of those options?  Alternatively, if your logic to show/hide is server-side then you can wrap this line in a conditional statement which checks that logic.

Comment: I want to hide it initially and then control its visibility from javascript. I'm able to control the visibility from Js but just want to hide it on load

Comment: In that case you'd either use an inline style or target it from your CSS styling (which doesn't have to be by a class, it just has to identify the element in some way).  Currently you're basically trying to use CSS without using CSS, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I think i confused you. left-menu-item is a CSS class with few styles. I'm trying to write a inline and trying to figure out the syntax to do it.

Comment: Oh, you just want to use an inline style?  Wouldn't that be the same syntax you use for the class?  Try: `@Html.NavItem("Card", "Cards", "Card", new { @class = "left-menu-item", style = "display: none;"})`

Comment: Thank you!! When i typed in style, VS didn't recognize it and made me confused. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for an inline style is essentially just adding another attriute to the resulting HTML element, exactly like the `class` attribute you add now.  So where you have this:

```
@Html.NavItem("Card", "Cards", "Card", new { @class = "left-menu-item"})
```

You'd do this:

```
@Html.NavItem("Card", "Cards", "Card", new { @class = "left-menu-item", style = "display: none;"})
```

That anonymous object in the `new { }` can contain anything you like and its properties will become attributes on the resulting HTML element.  (The only reason `class` has an `@` before it is because in C# `class` is already a reserved word.  This `@` syntax tells C# that this is an identifier and not a keyword.)